Spring Boot Service Code Generation based on API First Approach & Controlling the Generated Folder Structure
In our company we are following API First Methodology and presently using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate the models and api related code generated using the api.yml.
Our goal is to generate the code for rest of layers like Controller, Service, Repository layers, Integrations (with Kafka, Cache etc.,) based on the Data models definitions of my Service. Essentially have a CRUD implementation generated and connect it with API yml based code generation.
So my question is is there a way/support for generating a Spring boot Microservices with all the layers code based on the inputs namely api.yml and DB model?
I explored Yeoman generators, Modules & Blueprints in jhipster. Also tried to see of the openapi-generator has the extended capability to support CRUD and generate the Service & Repository layers. but could not find any mechanism. I could not find a generating capability which can use my api.yml and data model and generate all the spring boot Microservice layers
